# Surface mount package size 201-1

Tags: surface-mount

[image]Does anyone know what a 201-1 package size is, and how it might differ from a 'normal' 0201?

I found it in a MacBook schematic.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: With how stingy Apple is, where on earth did you find that schematic‽

Comment: Considering Apple it's probably a proprietary footprint.

Comment: A long time searching and collecting! You need some?

Comment: Could you post a picture of the spot you found it in?

Comment: @Mal No, I was just surprised. I'd encourage archiving it though! Maybe send a copy off to archive.org, because we both know Apple won't.

Comment: Maybe it is just the footprint.  Particular pad sizes and solder mask areas.  Fits a standard 0201, but for particular conditions (solder process or solder or temperature profile or whatever.)  Just guessing, though.

Comment: @JRE I'm new to the site, just ten minutes ago! Can I upload an image directly in a comment?

Comment: You can edit the question and put the picture there.

Comment: Done. It is from a 2012/13 MacBook Pro Retina A1425 820-3462-A motherboard, I believe. In this case, the components are part of the Thunderbolt circuitry.

Comment: It's probably just the first of a number of variants (probably 3) of the 0201 package. The three common variants, per IPC, are L, N, and M (**L**east, **N**ominal, and **M**ost, referring to footprint area). Perhaps Apple just uses 1, 2, and 3 instead of L, N, and M.

Comment: ...o-schematics.com seems the shown in the image. FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case size is standardized by the case numbers in mil as 0201 but the pad designs for the layout may different depending on IR reflow or glue and wave-solder to optimize solder low defect rates from surface tensions.

So the -1 is used for both the 0201 and 0402 parts which must use the same solder process and optimized pad geometry as recommended by IPC standards, as @Derstrom has reported on.  Although each company may choose deviations to IPC suggested by their partner CME assy shop to reduce costs associated with solder failures, the #1 test process failure. It is not just a just process failure but a design failure that must be collaborated with solder types preferred.

I know Apple likes to use no-clean flux process because it saves them a  buck, so they can sell more Apple products which void some warranties with the moisture detection indicators, because contrary to myth, no-clean flux is quite corrosive with moisture and will corrode a moist Mac or iPad in a couple days. I’ve been burnt a couple times.

Comment: Not sure about corrosion (and I sure it is not), but residues of some "no-clean" water-soluble fluxes can create shorts bdtween closely-spaced pins with below 1 k impedance in a bad rainy day, which will kill SMOS functionality for certain.

Comment: I am sure about the blue-green copper rust I found after my experiences with apple.

Comment: Metal oxides or rust are conductive , I agree and the moisture with that flux is deadly on exposed copper unlike resin types. The slight acidic nature of no clean flux makes it better for mass production soldering but worse for extreme. Humid environments with fan cooling and dust entrapment.